# how to hide a tableview row from a boolean value in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

This is my api response:

```
    [
{
                "id": "1cedf39c-633e-4bd4-b27e-0227c297fc6c",
                "mfs": {
                    "id": "42b68826-c516-4295-be03-97b37d2dc33a",
                    "name": "bKash",
                    "logo": "https://globpayassets.s3.amazonaws.com/mfs/10cf0702-0056-403d-bba7-60f6cafbc7b3.png",
                    "status": true
                },
                "mobileNumber": "01234",
                "recipientName": "abcd",
                "status": true
            }
]
```

I have to hide that particular row from this array where "status": false
here's my code for cellForRow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let mfsList = mfsListData?[indexPath.row]
                
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SendMoneyMFSTypeTableViewCellId", for: indexPath)as! SendMoneyMFSTypeTableViewCell
                cell.mfsNumberLabel.text = mfsList?.mobileNumber
                cell.mfsNameLabel.text = mfsList?.mfs?.name
                cell.mfsIcon.setImageFromURl(imageUrl: mfsList?.mfs?.logo ?? "")
            return cell
}
```

I have my data to load the cell in 'mfsList' & i have to check mfsList.status == false then hide that row.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Filter `mfsList` beforehand, and remove the value which have `status` `false`?

Comment: How to do it? can you help me out showing an example of it?

Comment: `mfsList = mfsList.filter { $0.status }` ? But look for Filter in Swift. And why `mfsList` is optional? And `mfs` property too can be nil?

Comment: yes mfs can be nil, I should have unwrap this.